# Slider no admite más imágenes

Tags: html, css

Verán el slider no me permite poner más de 4 imágenes sin que se rompa el poder ver solo de 1 en una las imágenes. creo que el problema está aquí en el .slider ul {width: 400%;}, he intentado variarlo pero no consigo hacer que respete la proporción, también he mirado en YT pero nada. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="Deslizante1.jpg" alt=""> </li>
    <li><img src="Deslizante2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="Deslizante3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="Deslizante4.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="Deslizante5.jpg" alt=""> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

/*Galería deslizante*/
.slider {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: none;
}
.slider ul {
display: flex;
padding: 0;
width: 400%;
animation-name: cambio;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite linear;
}
.slider li {
width: 100%;
border: none;
}
.slider img {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}
@keyframes cambio {
0% {margin-left: 0;}
20% {margin-left: 0;}

25% {margin-left: -100%;}
45% {margin-left: -100%;}

50% {margin-left: -200%;}
70% {margin-left: -200%;}

75% {margin-left: -300%;}
100% {margin-left: -300%;}
}
```

Comment: Tienes que colocar el html del slide completo, para que podamor ver si has cometido algún error de sintaxis, igual el js que ejecuta el slide

Comment: Buenas, el slide completo es el siguiente:                                                 `<div class="slider">
<ul><li><img src="Deslizante1.jpg" alt=""> </li> <li><img src="Deslizante2.jpg" alt=""></li> <li><img src="Deslizante3.jpg" alt=""></li>         <li><img src="Deslizante4.jpg" alt=""></li> <li><img src="Deslizante5.jpg" alt=""> </li></ul></div>`  y respecto al JS no precisa de ningún JS el slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que tienes que modificar tu `css` manualmente cada vez que tengas que ingresar un `slide nuevo`, no solo el `width` (de 400% a 500%...) sino también `@keyframe y sus porcentajes`, si a eso le sumas que también tienes que `agregarle segundos al tiempo de la animación (10s, 12.5s, ...)` si no quieres que las diapositivas vayan más rápidas a medida agregas slides.

Si tu intención es dejar el slide fijo con cierta cantidad de imagenes y no sufrirá modificaciones con el tiempo está bien, pero si no es así te recomiendo usar javascript o jquery, que hace el trabajo por tí cuando agreges una imagen más.